# Content Authoring Solution

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce

TinyMCE has Ephox Enterprise which gives content authoring solutions.

I want to know which are the other content authoring solutions available which may also be supported by TinyMCE.

Content Authoring Solutions in the sense which helps in tracking the changes and also which provides approvals based on roles/entitlements

Thanks